# How do I run a Perl one liner from a makefile?

Tags: perl, makefile

I know the perl one liner below is very simple, works and does a global substitution, A for a; but how do I run it in a makefile?

```
perl -pi -e "s/a/A/g" filename
```

I have tried (I now think the rest of the post is junk as the shell command does a command line expansion - NOT WHAT I WANT!) The question above still stands!

```
APP = $(shell perl -pi -e "s/a/A/g" filename)
```

with and without the following line

```
EXE = $(APP)
```

and I always get the following error

```
make: APP: Command not found
```

which I assume comes from the line that starts APP

Thanks

Comment: So what *is* the line that starts APP?  It sounds like you're doing something wrong there; the declaration of APP itself looks fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run perl as part of a target's action, you might use

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
        echo abc | perl -pe 's/a/A/g'
$ make
echo abc | perl -pe 's/a/A/g'
Abc
```

(Note that there's a TAB character before `echo`.)

Perl's `-i` option is for editing files in-place, but that will confuse `make` (unless perhaps you're writing a [phony target](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Phony-Targets.html)). A more typical pattern is to make targets from sources. For example:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: bAr

bAr: bar.in
        perl -pe 's/a/A/g' bar.in > bAr
$ cat bar.in
bar
$ make
perl -pe 's/a/A/g' bar.in > bAr
$ cat bAr
bAr
```

If you let us know what you're trying to do, we'll be able to give you better, more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should show the smallest possible Makefile which demonstrates your problem, and show how you are calling it.  Assuming your Makefile looks something like this, I get the error message.  Note that there is a tab character preceding the `APP` in the `all:` target.

```
APP = $(shell date)

all:
    APP
```

Perhaps you meant to do this instead:

```
APP = $(shell date)

all:
    $(APP)
```

I did not use your `perl` command because it does not run for me as-is.
Do you really mean to use Perl's substitution operator? `perl -pi -e "s/a/A/g"`

Here is a link to [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)  documentation.

Comment: Yes, I want to run a perl substitution on a file from a makefile. The real substitution is more complex but that's not the point.